# How can I find items with a field including N values inside?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have a field which includes varying number of multiple values for each item. I like to find items with N values in that field. How can I write this query for mongodb?

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56fde213ddf2ec32df886432"), 
"values" : ["A","B" ... ]
}
```

For this example I like to find items having N values in "values" field?

Comment: That's not a valid structure. Perhaps you mean `"values": ["A","B","C"]` instead.

Comment: You can't count fields, you can count arrays.  is that what you mean?

Comment: yeap counting array is the thing